# SharePoint 2013 uninstall

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Can any one share the step-by-step process of SharePoint 2013 uninstallation.

I am getting lot of errors if I am going through simple uninstallation process.

Answer (score 4):

It is better if you share the error you are getting. But here are the steps.

- Run the config wizard and remove the server from farms.
- Unistall the SharePoint from Control Panael
- Uninstall any language pack if any installed
- Manually delete the Web.config files, index files, log files, and customizations. might have are not automatically removed when you uninstall SharePoint
- SQL Server databases are detached but are not removed from the database server.

http://sharepoint-blog.com/uninstalling-sharepoint-2013-and-appfabric-1-1/